# scala - spark submit fails

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, sbt-assembly

i am doing an aggregation job on data present in aws s3, written in scala, created a sbt assembly standalone fat jar and running my scala job using spark-submit command in EMR cluster. but spark-submit fails. what am i missing here.

My project structure:

```
/Users/itru/IdeaProjects/mobilewalla/build.sbt
/Users/itru/IdeaProjects/mobilewalla/src/main/scala/metrics/India.scala
/Users/itru/IdeaProjects/mobilewalla/project/assembly.sbt
```

My Scala code in intellij:

```
package metrics
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object India {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("IndiaMetrics")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
println("Please Provide Input Path")
val input = readLine("prompt> ")
val DataRDD = sc.textFile(input).cache()
val schema = StructType(Array(StructField("device_id", StringType, true)
  , StructField("device_id_type", StringType, true)
  , StructField("Useragent", StringType, true)
  , StructField("ip_address", StringType, true)
  , StructField("event_date", StringType, true)
  , StructField("Lat", StringType, true)
  , StructField("Long", StringType, true)
  , StructField("country_cde", StringType, true)))

val rowRDD = DataRDD.map(_.split("\\|\\^")).map(e ⇒ Row(e(0), e(1), e(2), e(3), e(4), e(5), e(6), e(7)))
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val mobilewallaRDD = sqlContext.applySchema(rowRDD, schema)
mobilewallaRDD.registerTempTable("mobilewalla")
val DistDeviceIds = sqlContext.sql("select count(DISTINCT device_id) from mobilewalla")
DistDeviceIds.show()
val locEvePerDeviceID = sqlContext.sql("select device_id, count(DISTINCT Lat) as LocationEvents from mobilewalla Group by device_id order by LocationEvents desc")
locEvePerDeviceID.registerTempTable("LocationEventsCount")
val FreqCount = sqlContext.sql("Select LocationEvents,count(LocationEvents) as somanydeviceswithLocationEvents from LocationEventsCount Group by LocationEvents order by somanydeviceswithLocationEvents desc")
println("please provide output path")
val output = readLine("prompt> ")
FreqCount.coalesce(1)
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save(output)
 }
}
```

Code works entirely fine when i run it in local.

Below is my Build.sbt file:

```
name := "mobilewalla"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
{
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
}
assemblyJarName in assembly := "mobilewalla_metrics1.jar"
```

My assembly.sbt file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.2")
addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.7.2")
```

So far so good. `sbt compile`, `sbt run` and `sbt assembly` works fine and gives me a fat jar

i copied this jar to EMR cluster using scp command.

when i spark-submit job it says:

```
>spark-submit --class metrics.India  --master yarn-client  --num-executors 5 
--driver-memory 4g  --executor-memory 8g  --executor-cores 5  --jars mobilewalla_metrics1.jar 
Error: Must specify a primary resource (JAR or Python or R file)
```

I am unable to figure out where the issue is. what could be the problem am i missing anything here.

Comment: AFAIR `--jars` is for *additional* ones. Since you have only one, remove the `--jar` part and leave only `mobilewalla_metrics1.jar` at the end of `spark-submit`

Comment: Dude thanks a lot you made my day :)